# Рекурсивный метод, который принимает в качестве параметра значения массива

Tags: java

**Тема - Рекурсия.**

Для простоты понятия приведу такой пример.
Имеется метод:

```
public static int method(int a, int b){
    while (b > 0){
        int swap = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = swap;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Этот метод принимает два значения а и b, совершает операции над ними и возвращает значения типа int.

Идём дальше.

Нужно совершить действия над 4-мя числами вот так, которые берутся из массива int.

method(a,method(b,method(c,d)));

Вот что получилось у меня:

```
public static int nod(int[] array){
    System.out.println("\nДлина массива = " + array.length);
    int nod = 0;
    for(int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        while (array[i] > 0) {
            int swap = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i-1] % array[i];
            array[i-1] = swap;
            nod = array[i-1];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\nNOD = " + nod);
    return nod;
}
```

Но вот с рекурсией как быть.
4.2.2

Comment: Вот тут пример https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-array-elements-using-recursion/

Comment: Этот пример мне понятен. Но тут другое

Comment: То же самое. Просто у вас не операция суммы, а другая операция. Нужно эту часть переписать. Вот конкретно ваша задача https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gcd-two-array-numbers/ или https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890293/get-the-gcd-of-n-numbers/25890405#25890405

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static int nod(int[] array, int index = 0) {
  // check that array has at least two elements
  // ...

  if (index < array.length - 1)
    return method(array[index], nod(array, index + 1));
  else
    return method(array[index], array[index + 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот всё тело `nod()`, переделанное под рекурсию на скорую руку, возможно будут варианты лучше:

```
public static int nod(int[] array){
    System.out.println("\nДлина массива = " + array.length);
    int nod = method(array.length - 1, array);
    System.out.println("\nNOD = " + nod);
    return nod;
}

public static int method(int i, int[] array){
    if (array[i] <= 0) {
        return method(i - 1, array);
    }

    if (i == 0) {
        return array[i];
    }

    int swap = array[i];
    array[i] = array[i-1] % array[i];
    array[i-1] = swap;

    return method(i, array);
}
```